# ffplay how to change the seek interval

Tags: ffmpeg

I am completing a project in which I need to isolate single frames and their time stamps. I am using ffplay. using the "s" key I am able to stepwise move forward frame by frame. However when I try to move backwards a frame it jumps back 10 seconds. Is there a way to change this default based on my fps that the video was recorded at in order to jump back frame by frame?
There seems to be a command including seek_interval, but limited documentation on how to implement this for a 25fps video file.
Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to have your video re-encoded so it supports scrubbing. Basically a video can have P, I, and B frames. You need B frames in order to step back, otherwise you'll go back to the previous I frame. http://www.bretl.com/mpeghtml/pixtypes.HTM